# How to set current page URL for testing

Tags: unit-test

I need to test the following piece of code:

```
if (ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl().contains('ActiveParticipant'))
    Tab1Style = 'activeTab';
```

How can I set the URL so that the condition evaluates to true?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
//If your page is "ActiveParticipant" do as follows   
PageReference pageRef = Page.ActiveParticipant;
Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
```

Comment: Thanks! Your code helped me to figure it out. What I used was actually this: PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/ActiveParticipant'); Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

String baseURL = ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl();

if(baseURL.contains('ActiveParticipant')){
    Tab1Style = 'activeTab';
}